# Google calendar api without access

Tags: google-calendar-api

Is it possible to create event in google calendar without access to account? For example send special email and it will trigger a creation event

I have a site with my own calendar, many people create events, I want to duplicate event in user calendar, but I don't want to strain users with OAuth keys and other difficults

Comment: Send an email with an `.ics` attachment.

Answer (score 0):

When the users give you their google mail adress you can add them as **Attendees** to your event.

The event will then be shown in their calendars.

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/concepts/sharing#inviting_attendees_to_events